# Is $W \otimes V^\ast \cong \mathrm{Hom}(V,W)$ canonical?

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, tensors, vector-space-isomorphism

Given two finite-dimensional vector spaces $V$ and $W$ there is an isomorphism $\mathrm{Hom}(V,W) \cong V^\ast \otimes W$. One way to construct it is to observe that the map $V^\ast \times W \to \mathrm{Hom}(V,W)$ that sends a pair $(\omega,v) \in V^\ast \times W$ to the linear map $ u \mapsto \omega(u)v$ is in fact bilinear, hence, by the universal property of the tensor product, it specifies a unique linear map from $V^\ast \otimes W$ to $\mathrm{Hom}(V,W)$, which can be shown to be an isomorphism.

Now, one could also start with a bilinear map $W \times V^\ast \to \mathrm{Hom}(V,W)$ defined by sending $(v,\omega) \in W \times V^\ast$ to the map $u \mapsto \omega(u)v$. By the same reasoning, this will lift to an isomorphism between $W\otimes V^\ast$ and $\mathrm{Hom}(V,W)$.

Is there anything that would make the same isomorphism somehow more "canonical" than the second, since this is the order in which it always appears in the literature?

Comment: yes, the tensor product is in general monoidal cats not symmetric, in particular $V\otimes W$ and $W \otimes V$ can be completely different objects. However, your computation above is just the tensor Hom adjunction and that one holds in a lot more places as it is hardwired in the definition of a closed monoidal cat

Comment: My question came up after noticing that, when introducing the tensor algebra not much of a distinction is made between elements of $V^\ast \otimes V$ and of $V \otimes V^\ast$, since one speaks just of (1,1) tensors. Hence I ask whether the identification $V^\ast \otimes W \cong \mathrm{Hom}(V,W)$ is canonical or a matter of convention (I don't see a strong reason to take the second iso that I give as more or less canonical than the first).

Comment: In general language speaking, the identification with $V^*\otimes W \cong \mathrm{Hom(V,W)}$ is more canonical, as it does arise as a combination of $\mathbb{k}$ being the unit of the closed monoidal cat and the tensor hom adjunction (also you should make clear that you see $\mathrm{Hom}(V,W)$ as vector spaces). Whereas the other morphism needs to also compose with the braiding isomorphism (for which you need a braided closed monoidal category). However, in the case of Vectorspaces (which is symmetric closed monoidal) I completely see why there might be no obvious reason why one is preferable.